# Cannot deoploy nuxt 3 to netlify with using Swiper

Tags: vuejs3, netlify, swiper.js, rollup, nuxtjs3

I'm Trying to deploy Nuxt 3 on netlify but I'm getting this error log:

**3:16:10 PM: [error] [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "Swiper" from "plugins/swiper.ts".
3:16:10 PM: This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
3:16:10 PM: If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
3:16:10 PM: `build.rollupOptions.external`**

this is my plugin/swiper.ts:

```
import SwiperClass, { Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay, Parallax } from 'Swiper'
import VueAwesomeSwiper from 'vue-awesome-swiper'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'vue-awesome-swiper';

// import swiper module styles
import 'swiper/css'
import 'swiper/css/pagination'
import 'swiper/css/navigation';


SwiperClass.use([Navigation, Pagination])
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueAwesomeSwiper, SwiperClass, Swiper, SwiperSlide)
})
```

and here I'm using the component:

```
<template> 
    <swiper class="parallax-slider relative" :pagination="{ clickable: true }" :controller="true" navigation
        :allow-slide-next="true" parallax grabCursor :allow-touch-move="true" :slides-per-view="1">
        <swiper-slide v-for="image in images" style="; ">
            <img class="h-80 w-full object-cover" :src="image.imageUrl" alt="">

        </swiper-slide>
    </swiper>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

let images = reactive([{
    id: 1, imageUrl: "https://assets.safaraq.com/images/800/trips/79b5edebe8fe1c9a14cbffcd49dca6a3DI4614.jpg",
},
{
    id: 2, imageUrl: "https://assets.safaraq.com/images/800/trips/79b5edebe8fe1c9a14cbffcd49dca6a37Nh398.jpg",
},
{
    id: 3, imageUrl: "https://assets.safaraq.com/images/800/trips/79b5edebe8fe1c9a14cbffcd49dca6a3xc3946.jpg"
},
{
    id: 4, imageUrl: "https://assets.safaraq.com/images/800/trips/79b5edebe8fe1c9a14cbffcd49dca6a310P156.jpg",
},
{
    id: 5, imageUrl: "https://assets.safaraq.com/images/800/trips/79b5edebe8fe1c9a14cbffcd49dca6a3zSf839.jpg",
},
])
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to add swiper to your build transpile inside nuxt.config.ts ?

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  build: {
    transpile: ['swiper']
  }
});
```

I find the answer on https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/5842

Comment: Thank you, i spent 2 hours on this. Cheers

Comment: mark this then.